# horizontal scrolling on the web page test

Tags: testing, scroll, automated-tests, e2e-testing, testcafe

How to write a test for horizontal scrolling on the web page with Test Cafe

As being new to automation testing as well to the Test Cafe I can't find an example of a test for horizontal scrolling with Test cafe.

Answer (score 2):

TestCafe does not provide the separate `scroll` action, however, TestCafe performs a scroll automatically when you call any action. For example, if you need to scroll to some element, you can use the [hover](https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/documentation/test-api/actions/hover.html) action.

If you still need to scroll your page without any action, you can use the [ClientFunction](https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/documentation/test-api/obtaining-data-from-the-client/) mechanism. Please see the following code:

```
import { ClientFunction } from 'testcafe';

const browserscroll = ClientFunction(function() {
    window.scrollBy(0,1000)
});

test('Test', async t => {
    await browserscroll();
});
```

UPDATED:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <style>
        #scroll-container {
            overflow: scroll;
            width: 800px;
            height: 800px;
        }

        #scroll-content {
            height: 5000px;
            width: 5000px;
            background-color: blue;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="scroll-container">
        <div id="scroll-content"></div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Test Code:

```
import { Selector, ClientFunction } from 'testcafe';

fixture `My first fixture`
    .page `../pages/index.html`;

const scrollContainer = Selector('#scroll-container');
const scrollFn = ClientFunction(scrollValue => {
    scrollContainer().scrollLeft = scrollValue;
}, { dependencies: { scrollContainer } });

test('My first test', async t => {
    await scrollFn(1000);

    await t.debug();
});
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. In my case, I have to scroll container and I can't find a way to do so.

Comment: I've updated my answer with an example with a scrollable container

Comment: @AlexKamaev is it possible to pass the selector in as a parameter to the ClientFunction?